# No metadata registered for captured table ORCLCDB.ROOT.TEST

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

After inserting something on TEST table this error occurs.

```
[2020-02-15 15:20:03,996] ERROR Producer failure (io.debezium.pipeline.ErrorHandler:36)
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No metadata registered for captured table ORCLCDB.ROOT.TEST**
    at io.debezium.pipeline.EventDispatcher.errorOnMissingSchema(EventDispatcher.java:168)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.EventDispatcher.dispatchDataChangeEvent(EventDispatcher.java:138)
    at io.debezium.connector.oracle.LcrEventHandler.dispatchDataChangeEvent(LcrEventHandler.java:102)
    at io.debezium.connector.oracle.LcrEventHandler.processLCR(LcrEventHandler.java:76)
    at oracle.streams.XStreamOut.XStreamOutReceiveLCRCallbackNative(Native Method)
    at oracle.streams.XStreamOut.receiveLCRCallback(XStreamOut.java:465)
    at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(OracleStreamingChangeEventSource.java:74)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

connector-oracle-source.properties:

```
name=oracle-connector
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector
tasks.max=1
database.hostname=192.168.6.36
database.port=1521
database.user=c##xstrm
database.password=xs
database.server.name=osTomates
database.out.server.name=teucude4
database.dbname=ORCLCDB
#database.pdb.name=ORCLPDB1
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=192.168.6.36:9092
database.history.kafka.topic=test
```

Please let me know if you need additional information?

Oracle 19 version
Standalone configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user c##xstrm should get permission to see the root.test table (on my case).

GRANT SELECT ON root.test TO c##xstrm;

This solved my problem.

If next you after restart the kafka connect and you get this error ORA-31603, this worked for me:

GRANT select_catalog_role TO c##xstrm;

Hope this helps someone out there.